# Flutter error on debug "app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

The app worked well during debugging until I integrated Firebase.

I added the necessary Firebase dependencies and followed the setup steps.

Attempted `flutter clean`, `flutter pub cache repair`, and cache invalidation, but the issue persisted.

```
"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibsTask$MergeNativeLibsTaskWorkAction
   > Input/output error"
```